# Suggest tag deletion

Tags: discussion, tags

How can I suggest a tag deletion? I guess this is some privilege after some rep points. But in general, is there a process for any user to suggest a new tag or the deletion of an existing tag?

For now, I suggest a tag deletion with this post. I see that there is a tag [fd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fd) (with zero watchers) which is just an alias to the `find` command for some people maybe. Not universal, not standard, when you see that you think of "floppy disk" or "file descriptor", obviously this is confusing and if it was useful, it would have some watchers.

---

Update:

- There is a program named `fd`, its description says it is "a simple, fast and user-friendly alternative to find." [reference](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)
- There are 7 questions tagged [fd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fd) as of today, 3 of them intentionally used this tag to match this program, while 4 of them used it to mean "file descriptors".

Comment: Quick notes: meta is usually the right way to have this conversation. `fd` is a real program (https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), so probably the tag needs to be removed when it’s about file-descriptors?

Answer (score 4):

As of my understanding, to suggest a tag addition / deletion / modification, we can post a question here, tagging with some of the `tag*` tags.

---

For this specific case, I don't think that it is necessary to remove [fd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fd) tag, if even a few users find it is useful for them, then it's ok for me. Also I see this program is available though repos like packman, so it fits here.

Also few are the people confused by this tag, so I will edit these old questions to change their tag to [file-descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-descriptor).